# UWP C# To Display AudioDevice DeviceInformation to Textblock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I am having some issue to display my saved USB Audio Adapter name on a `textblock`when i load it from `ApplicationDataContainer`

when selecting the from the `listbox`, the `deviceId`is able to be displayed properly on the `textblock`

```
private void audioRenderList_P_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        mediaPlayer_CH1.AudioDevice = renderDeviceList_P[audioRenderList_P.SelectedIndex];
        renderDeviceName_P.Text = renderDeviceList_P[audioRenderList_P.SelectedIndex].Name.ToString();
    }

if (mediaPlayer_CH1.AudioDevice.Id != null)
        {
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

            localSettings.Values["audioRenderSettings_P"] = mediaPlayer_CH1.AudioDevice.Id;
        }
```

[image]

However, when loading of saved audio `deviceId` it couldn't be displayed as readable characters;

```
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    if (localSettings.Values["audioRenderSettings_P"] != null)
    {
        var audioSource = localSettings.Values["audioRenderSettings_P"] as string;
        mediaPlayer_CH1.AudioDevice = await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(audioSource);
        renderDeviceName_P.Text = audioSource;
    }
    else renderDeviceName_P.Text = "Select Audio Device ..";
```

[image]

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SelectionChanged` event, you are displaying the **Name** and saving the **Id**. But when loading, you are showing **Id**, they are not same.

When loading, you can change code to:

```cs
var audioSource = localSettings.Values["audioRenderSettings_P"] as string;
mediaPlayer_CH1.AudioDevice = await DeviceInformation.CreateFromIdAsync(audioSource);
renderDeviceName_P.Text = mediaPlayer_CH1.AudioDevice.Name.ToString();
```

Best regards.

Comment: Another question, as I am doing this for `audio render` device. Is there any difference for `audio capture` device?